# How to set height and border of bootstrap tabs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal and a nav-tab  in that modal .There are **2 issues**.

- First is that those tabs are very large in height ,I want to set their height a bit less in size .I have tried to set their height using css height property,but its not working for me.
- My second issue is that, when particular tab is opened then the border-bottom/ line showing at bottom of that tab is not getting hidden,as it should do normally.I want to hide that bottom line of the tab when it is open .

So, please can anyone help me to solve the above issues.
Here is the image of my modal with the tabs:
[image]

here is my **code** for these tabs (i am avoiding unnecessary code):

```
<div class="tabbable" >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ><!--tabs-->
          <li  style="position:absolute;margin-left:0px;height:50px;" id="logintab">
               <a href="#pane_login" data-toggle="tab" id="logintab_a">Login</a></li>
          <li  class="active" style="margin-left:70px;" id="reg_tab" >
              <a href="#pane_reg" data-toggle="tab" id="regtab_a">Registration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_login" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_register" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>
</div><!--/Tabbable-->
```

Comment: Fiddle your code..It would be easier to make corrections.

Comment: providing css will be much better

Answer (score 11):

Sharing my solution just in case someone else has to adjust the height:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a
{
    /* adjust padding for height*/
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

The second issue could be resolved by adjusting margin of active anchor

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a
{
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}
.nav-tabs > li.active {
    margin-bottom: -1px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `First issue` use `height:43px`

And for second you have to set `border-bottom:none` like,

**CSS**

```
li{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0px;
    height:43px;
}
li.active{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabbable" >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ><!--tabs-->
          <li style="" id="logintab">
               <a href="#pane_login" data-toggle="tab" id="logintab_a">Login</a></li>
          <li class="active" id="reg_tab" >
              <a href="#pane_reg" data-toggle="tab" id="regtab_a">Registration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_login" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
        <div id="pane_register" class="tab-pane active">
        </div>
     </div>
</div><!--/Tabbable-->
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwt43/)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm taking a demo of @Rohan Kumar.

Just changes of css: you need to do as the following

First Issue: you need to set border-bottom as the below contents background as if you are using full border

```
li.active {
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
```

Second Issue: you can do as @Rohan Kumar by defining the height or you can set margin and padding to 0 if needed increase the padding value for top and bottom.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwt43/1/)