# Changing the height of Bootstrap's nav-pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698925/how-to-set-height-and-border-of-bootstrap-tabs) is quite close to what I am looking for, but still didn't help to rich the goal after several hours. I'm just trying to decrease a bit the height of bootstrap tab pills by editing the original Bootstrap.css file.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL1p7gf8/)

I've removed the original file link from the External resources and placed the raw code in the css section so that it's possible to experiment

[image]

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="task_management_tab">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tasks_private">A</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="">B</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="">C</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fwt43/131/ ?

Comment: Added the jsFiddle

Comment: Just decrease padding to .nav > li > a

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For nav pills, decrease the padding like so:

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The default is `10px`

I'd suggest not amending the actual bootstrap css though as it'll affect a number of other things. Target your nav pills with your own custom class.

Comment: are there no CSS classes to modify the size similar to button's btn-sm, btn-xs etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap 4, try using p- for padding or m- for margin

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link p-2" id="pills-listado-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-listado" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </li>
```