# Altering height of Python/Dash Navigation Pills?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, nav-pills

I have a Python/Dash application with a vertical nav-bar and I wish to alter the height of the nav-pills. I'm using the bootstrap "SLATE" theme with the CSS-file stored locally in the `/asset` directory.
[image]

The sidebar code:

```
SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    #"background-color": "#4F5761",
}

    sidebar = html.Div([
            html.P("MySidebar"),
            html.Hr(),
            dbc.Nav(
                [dbc.NavLink("Section 1", href="/page_1", active="exact"),
                 dbc.NavLink("Section 2", href="/page_2", active="exact"),
                 dbc.NavLink("Section 3", href="/page_3", active="exact"),],
                vertical=True,
                pills=True,),
            ],
            style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,)
```

I found a similar question in this thread
[Changing the height of Bootstrap's nav-pills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096421/changing-the-height-of-bootstraps-nav-pills)
suggesting the following extension to the CSS but I cannot figure out how to apply it.

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Question:** How can I (in a Python/Dash context) extend the original bootstrap CSS to change height of the pills?
I'd prefer to leave the bootstrap CSS untouched and override the specific properties needed in a separate small CSS. What properties should I change and how do I introduce another CSS-file that overrides these specific properties in the original one (which CSS overrides the other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should create an assets folder in the same directory where the python file exists.
2. Create a CSS file in the assets folder and put your CSS style.

   - main_file.py
   - assets/
     |-- style.css
3. Run your python file, the CSS file will be applied automatically.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't really answer my question. I already have an assets folder with a local CSS-file as stated in the question. To clarify; can I add another CSS file in the same folder overriding some of the properties in the original bootstrap file and - and this is the core of the question - which properties do I need to introduce/override to get the desired change of the Nav Pill height?

Comment: @Pman70 Yes, local CSS files will override the properties of the bootstrap file. Which properties do I need to .... , use the same in the question `.nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}` try it and tell me if that fixes your problem.

Comment: It works now if I change the CSS snippet to `.nav-link{
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}`. Thanks for your help.